# How to use javax.mail in Tomcat 7 inside openshift v3?

Tags: java, tomcat, openshift

I use to have a site running in openshift v2, from where I could send a email using javax.mail.

But after migrating to openshift v3 the email function stopped working.

Now I just get a NoSuchProviderException. How ever I found this page: [Might be a reson](https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/cannot-send-email-due-to-javax-mail-nosuchproviderexception-smtp-error-154079.html)

I can compile the code with these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
<version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
<artifactId>mailapi</artifactId>
<version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If I try with booth I get "NoSuchProviderException: smtp"

If I try only with com.sun.mail I get "NoSuchProviderException: smtp"

If I try only with javax.mail I get NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mail/util/MailLogger (this class is included in the other com.sun.mail-jar)

Is there any other libs that might already be shipped with tomcat 7 (that I assume is the webserver in openshift v3) that perhaps I should use instead of these two I have found?

Or do you guys see any other solution?

Best regards
Fredrik

Comment: Try to add one more dependency `<groupid>javax.mail</groupid>
 <artifactid>mail</artifactid>`

Comment: Another way, you can try to mark your dependecies or one of them as `<scope>provided</scope>` or `<scope>compile</scope>`. It can help because openshift v3 env can already have mailing libs, which is causing conflict, but you still need your dependecies at compile time.

Comment: Hello Amigo! You solved it!! I replaced my dependencies with just yours, in scope compile and with version 1.5.0-b01 then it worked!! Best regards!

Comment: I might be a bit stupid here, but how do I mark your answer as a solution? Aha there is a arrow next to your post that looks like some mark_this_as_a_solution. Hope this is the right thing to do. Btw thank you so much for your time and help!!